# find function in nested dictionaries based on sentence

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, nlp

I am working on language processing. I receive a string (for example from speech recognition). The string contains some command that has to be **found**. I put together my own system, but I can't figure the algorithm for it (I am new to programming and to python).

Easy example:

```
received_string = 'I want to turn on machine'


# idea dictionary in dictionary
# commands
def function1():
    pass
def function2():
    pass

commands = \
{
    'I want to turn on ': {
                            'machine': function1,
                            'lights': function2
                        },

    'Open the ':        {
                            #####
                            #####
                        }

}
```

So basically I receive for example 'I want to turn on machine'. "I want to turn on" is command that can be applied to one of several objects. I want to store these objects in a dictionary_ inside the `commands` dictionary. Is it possible to find&implement some clever algorithm that will process 'I want to turn on machine' to 'I want to turn on' and then find the object 'machine' and execute `function1()`?

I don't really want to have algorithm that cut last word in a string and then search. The reason is I want dictionaries with questions and so on and there is not point to cut it. In fact I want really complex system and this dictionary with commands and different object is hindering my progress. I know there is a solution to make just two independent commands 'I want to turn on machine' and 'I want to turn on lights', but it's a bit unprofessional and not practicable right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
received_string = 'I want to turn on machine'


# idea dictionary in dictionary
# commands
def function1():
    print 'Function 1'
def function2():
    print 'Function 2'

commands = \
{
    'I want to turn on ': {
                            'machine': function1,
                            'lights': function2
                        },

    'Open the ':        {
                            #####
                            #####
                        }

}

for command in commands:
    if command in received_string:
        item = received_string.split(command)[-1].strip()
        cmd_out = commands[command][item]
        break

cmd_out()
```

This will return:

```
Function 1
```

Basically, you can see if your key from the commands is in your received string.  Then you can parse the command to see what you are performing the command on and set a variable to your function that is in the last part of your dictionary.  Once you are out of the loop, you can call your function variable.

For the moment, this assumes that your string is going to be something that is found in your dictionary, so if there is any error handling that needs to be done on that, it will need to be added.  But this will work in general for inputs that you know are in the dictionary.

Comment: No problem, I have found that it is generally easier to find out if the substring is in a larger string than to see if a string contains a certain substring, at least from a simple programming standpoint.